# Can't add profiles to contribution page (DB Error: constraint violation)

Tags: wordpress, profile

I am getting the same problem that is described [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/db-error-constraint-violation-when-i-try-to-add-profiles-to-contribution-page) and [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10895/cant-add-profile-to-contribution-page), but I can't find a clear resolution on either of these pages.

I am working with a fresh install of CiviCRM 4.7.11 on Wordpress 4.6.1. This is running on an AWS EC2 running Ubuntu 14.04. When attempting to create a membership signup page, the profiles tab contains a text box instead of drop-down menus. I created a custom profile after I observed this behavior, and am unable to access a selection mechanism to select the profile I created or any of the stock profiles.

[image: This is what I see.]

When I look at the console log for errors, these two errors appear consistently:

[image: Console error output]

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem came with the theme I had activated (Nimva by Rockythemes). I haven't been able to troubleshoot exactly what caused it (and likely won't have time anytime soon) but switching to a default theme and even leaving all the plugins activated allowed the dropdown menus to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue recently and the issue was with the plugin 'WPBakery Visual Composer' that caused the issue. We deactivate the plugin, add the profile and reactivate it. We suspect it is a setting within the plugin but haven't identified it yet. I will update when we do.